# PHP Large CSV Find and replace not working

Tags: php, csv

I have a script that is searching a large CSV file for instances of `\" and replacing it with just`"`. The code I have now is:

```
$sourcePath = 'EstablishmentExport.csv';
$targetPath = 'custom-alpharoomsuk-establishmentexport.csv';
$source = fopen($sourcePath, 'r');
$target = fopen($targetPath, 'w');

while(! feof($source))
  {
  $line = str_replace('Villege\"', 'Villege"', fgets($source));
  fwrite($target, $line);
  }

fclose($source);
fclose($target);
```

The issue here is it isnt replacing through my entire file. When I tested it in a small text file it works.  But in the big CSV it wont replace it.

The line in the CSV is as follows:
`"{A1306040-57DD-43BE-9328-55518FE52}","Tstufff","Fennel","No. 1-5ei Road, Checheng Villege\","","Pinljkgtung","","945","Nan-shih-pu","3 Star","","TW","0","test."`

Can anyone tell me why it isnt replacing Villege? The script has to run on the server would a unix command executed by UNIX do a better job like php_exec?

Comment: How big of a CSV are we talking?  Do you have error reporting enabled?  Does the script output anything to tell you whether or not it completed without errors?  It's possible the large CSV is overrunning the amount of memory allotted to PHP.

Comment: @SuperJer 200k+ lines. I did think of that but I am not loading the entire file into memory instead I am using FGET to read it line by line. And no errors it just executes fine but doesnt do anything.

Comment: @SuperJer I thought I would try this instead as I think fget is running out of memory too. `exec ( 'sed -i 's/\\"/"/g' somefile.csv' );` but it didnt work. Am I making a mistake here?

Comment: Difficult to say without looking at the file itself.  If you open it in Notepad++, you can turn on special character view.  This is always handy for spotting issues with CSV formats.  There's nothing wrong with having PHP do this for you.  It is a powerful multi-purpose language.

Comment: @Superjer I turned on the special character view and there doesn't seem to be anything there that's weird that would throw of the search and replace. Do you thing that as the file is so big that it is running out of memory even though I'm using fgets?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears the issue may in fact lie with your CSV.  My bet is your CSV lines are terminated with a NEWLINE character `\n`.  From what I can tell, `fgets` splits on CARRIAGE RETURN, `\r`.  I'm supposing that in Notepad++, under the special characters view, all the lines of your CSV only had a trailing `LF`?  So what happens is the entire 200,000+ line CSV gets loaded as a single string.

Now it is unclear in your question whether the script worked and simply failed to replace all occurrences, or if it had no effect at all.

I duplicated your code, and created a similar CSV file, and tested with all 3 forms of line terminations `\r`, `\r\n`, and `\n`.  I also put in a loop counter to tell me how many times it ran through the loop.  When the lines were terminated with only `\n`, the output said only 1 line was found and processed.

My environment has a much higher memory limit than the default for PHP, so it ran without a problem all 3 times, but in the case of `\n`, it will have used a substantially greater amount of memory, potentially halting an environment using default configuration.

All that being said, I recommend using `stream_get_line()` instead.  It works pretty much like `fgets()`, with the difference that you can specify your line termination character.

Try replacing your line containing `fgets()` with this one:

```
$line = str_replace('Villege\"', 'Villege"', stream_get_line($source, 65535, "\n"));
```

The 65535 in there is to limit the amount of characters a given line may have.  This number is substantially high enough to likely accommodate your situation.

Comment: Thank you so much, but I thought `CR``LF` which is what I see in Notepad ++ is a carriage return. How did you know it was a `\n` and not a `\r` ? How can I see that in Notepad ++ so I can debug situations like this in the future :)

Comment: `\n` in PHP is `LF` in N++, and `\r` in PHP is `CR` in N++.  Also, N++ has an 'extended' Find-Replace that can use these escape characters for searching and replacing.  That's how I created the 3 test CSV's for the 3 different situations.

Answer (score 0):

PHP isn't really designed for this. Offload the work to a different process and call it or start it from PHP. I suggest using Python or Perl.

Go through following link

[Parsing Large Text Files with PHP Without Killing the Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1255145/parsing-large-text-files-with-php-without-killing-the-server)

Comment: is there anyway to do this with PHP_EXEC with shell instead of pearl or python?

Comment: I tried this with no luck `exec ( 'sed -i 's/\\"/"/g' somefile.csv' );` why didnt this work?